# A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks

Tags: android, android-strictmode

I am getting this message in logcat

> A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released.
> See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.

Where do I look for the leak and what does it mean by " See java.io.Closeable".

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That means you have opened something but never close them.[`Closable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Closeable.html) have a method `close` which you must call to release the resources associated with the component when you no longer need it.

To look for the leak, you can try [`MAT`](http://android-developers.blogspot.kr/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html), I often use it to find memory leaks(static data holding a reference to Activity, etc).

Answer (score 8):

For me the problem happened because I was overriding the method `onBackPressed()` without calling the `super()`

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    //some coding here
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Answer (score 6):

if you see something like:

```
10-12 16:46:44.719 2710-2719/? E/StrictMode: A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
10-12 16:46:44.719 2710-2719/? E/StrictMode: java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'end' not called
10-12 16:46:44.719 2710-2719/? E/StrictMode:     at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:184)
10-12 16:46:44.719 2710-2719/? E/StrictMode:     at java.util.zip.Inflater.<init>(Inflater.java:82)
10-12 16:46:44.719 2710-2719/? E/StrictMode:     at com.android.okio.GzipSource.<init>(GzipSource.java:57)
10-12 16:46:44.719 2710-2719/? E/StrictMode:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.initContentStream(HttpEngine.java:490)
```

in your stacktrace, there is a known bug in older versions of okhttp that you can avoid by forcing the use of a newer version in your gradle file.

compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0'

that solved a very similar problem for me at least.

Comment: I'm using 3.10.0 but I still have this problem. any comment?

Comment: This error occurs on Emulator with Android api 27, but not on api 29.

Answer (score 3):

The same error message also shows up when there is a problem in `AndroidManifest.xml`. For me, the `<activity>` tag accidentally went out of `<application>`

This is correct:

```
<application ... >
    ...
    <activity ... />
</application>
```

This will result in *"A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released"* when starting the activity:

```
<application ... >
    ...
</application>

<activity ... />
```

Answer (score 1):

This has happened to me while launching a second activity from another activity when I did not declare the second activity in Application.mk.

Answer (score 1):

For me, it seems that is something related to emulator, as it disappeared by changing to another emulator.
you can test on real device.

Answer (score -4):

My error was caused by enabling the strict mode. When I was doing redeployments on a test phone using adb, some resources were not closed correctly.

I "fixed" the error by removing deathPenalty from the strict mode:

```
            StrictMode.setVmPolicy(new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder()
                    .detectAll()
                    .penaltyLog()
//                    .penaltyDeath()
                    .build());
```

Comment: This is not a proper fix if the quote-unquote wasn't noticed.

Comment: Best fix ever :D

Comment: I kind of agree with vanomart. Maybe this problem doesn't always kill the app? But for me it did and eventually I wanted to move on since I couldn't find the source. I don't get what the benefit is with the penaltyDeath() except that this error wont go unnoticed, but what I do right now is watch all the stacktrace for errors so it makes no sense that the app has to die for me. I would of course prefer to know what causes it but I guess it is different sources of the problem for everybody?

Comment: You got down voted because that just hides problem, it doesn't fix the fact you opened resources that get didn't closed.