# 'A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released ' error when a receiver is starting an IntentService

Tags: java, android, android-intentservice, android-broadcastreceiver

I have a `BroadcastReceiver` which calls a `IntentService`. I am getting the following error when the receiver code is finished running.

```
Error
 'A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
    java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'release' not called'
```

Here is my code:

```
public class RestartReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String TAG = "RestartReceiver";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();
        ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        final NetworkInfo wifi = connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
        final NetworkInfo mobile = connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
        if (wifi.isConnected() || mobile.isConnected()) {
            Intent downloadIntent=new Intent(context,DownloadService.class);
            context.startService(downloadIntent);
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "No Network Connectivity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25544021/a-resource-was-acquired-at-attached-stack-trace-but-never-released-see-java-io

Comment: The link is useful. How can i figure out, where is this error occurring ?

Comment: Try MAT from accepted answer. Posting `DownloadService` code might help us figuring out