# Anyone knows where these errors come from?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Here's the errors I get, if you need the activities or xml just says and I will post it ;)

Don't know if its because the images or what please help ...Thank you so much it means a lot :D

```
04-02 14:00:48.128 1448-1448/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                             Process: app.alexdickson.com.workout1, PID: 1448
                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{app.alexdickson.com.workout1/app.alexdickson.com.workout1.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
                                              Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:310)
                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:279)
                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:253)
                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
                                                 at app.alexdickson.com.workout1.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)
                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257) 
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)

04-02 14:01:28.432 1415-1424/? E/StrictMode: A resource was acquired         at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for   information on avoiding resource leaks.
                                         java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'close' not called
                                             at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:184)
                                             at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.<init>(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:180)
                                             at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor$1.createFromParcel(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:916)
                                             at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor$1.createFromParcel(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:906)
                                             at android.app.IBackupAgent$Stub.onTransact(IBackupAgent.java:71)
                                             at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:446)

04-02 14:01:28.441 1415-1424/? E/StrictMode: A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
                                         java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'close' not called
                                             at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:184)
                                             at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.<init>(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:180)
                                             at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor$1.createFromParcel(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:916)
                                             at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor$1.createFromParcel(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:906)
                                             at android.app.IBackupAgent$Stub.onTransact(IBackupAgent.java:64)
                                             at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:446)
04-02 14:01:28.470 1415-1424/? E/StrictMode: A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
                                         java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'close' not called
                                             at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:184)
                                             at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.<init>(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:180)
                                             at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor$1.createFromParcel(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:916)
                                             at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor$1.createFromParcel(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:906)
                                             at android.app.IBackupAgent$Stub.onTransact(IBackupAgent.java:57)
                                             at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:446)


04-02 14:01:32.716 1572-1581/? E/StrictMode: A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
                                         java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'close' not called
                                             at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:184)
                                             at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.<init>(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:180)
                                             at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor$1.createFromParcel(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:916)
                                             at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor$1.createFromParcel(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:906)
                                             at android.app.IBackupAgent$Stub.onTransact(IBackupAgent.java:57)
                                             at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:446)
04-02 14:01:32.721 1572-1581/? E/StrictMode: A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
                                         java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'close' not called
                                             at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:184)
                                             at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.<init>(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:180)
                                             at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor$1.createFromParcel(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:916)
                                             at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor$1.createFromParcel(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:906)
                                             at android.app.IBackupAgent$Stub.onTransact(IBackupAgent.java:64)
                                             at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:446)
04-02 14:01:32.723 1572-1581/? E/StrictMode: A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
                                         java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'close' not called
                                             at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:184)
                                             at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.<init>(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:180)
                                             at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor$1.createFromParcel(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:916)
                                             at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor$1.createFromParcel(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:906)
                                             at android.app.IBackupAgent$Stub.onTransact(IBackupAgent.java:71)
                                             at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:446)
04-02 14:01:32.929 1588-1597/? E/StrictMode: A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
                                         java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'close' not called
                                             at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:184)
                                             at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.<init>(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:180)
                                             at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor$1.createFromParcel(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:916)
                                             at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor$1.createFromParcel(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:906)
                                             at android.app.IBackupAgent$Stub.onTransact(IBackupAgent.java:57)
                                             at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:446)
04-02 14:01:32.932 1588-1597/? E/StrictMode: A resource was acquired    at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
                                         java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'close' not called
                                             at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:184)
                                             at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.<init>(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:180)
                                             at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor$1.createFromParcel(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:916)
                                             at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor$1.createFromParcel(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:906)
                                             at android.app.IBackupAgent$Stub.onTransact(IBackupAgent.java:64)
                                             at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:446)
04-02 14:01:32.934 1588-1597/? E/StrictMode: A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
                                         java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'close' not called
                                             at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:184)
                                             at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.<init>(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:180)
                                             at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor$1.createFromParcel(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:916)
                                             at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor$1.createFromParcel(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:906)
                                             at android.app.IBackupAgent$Stub.onTransact(IBackupAgent.java:71)
                                             at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:446)
04-02 14:01:33.634 1607-1616/? E/StrictMode: A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
                                         java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'close' not called
                                             at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:184)
                                             at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.<init>(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:180)
                                             at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor$1.createFromParcel(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:916)
                                             at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor$1.createFromParcel(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:906)
                                             at android.app.IBackupAgent$Stub.onTransact(IBackupAgent.java:57)
                                             at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:446)
04-02 14:01:33.646 1607-1616/? E/StrictMode: A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
                                         java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'close' not called
                                             at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:184)
                                             at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.<init>(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:180)
                                             at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor$1.createFromParcel(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:916)
                                             at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor$1.createFromParcel(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:906)
                                             at android.app.IBackupAgent$Stub.onTransact(IBackupAgent.java:64)
                                             at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:446)
04-02 14:01:33.648 1607-1616/? E/StrictMode: A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
                                         java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'close' not called
                                             at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:184)
                                             at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.<init>(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:180)
                                             at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor$1.createFromParcel(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:916)
                                             at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor$1.createFromParcel(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:906)
                                             at android.app.IBackupAgent$Stub.onTransact(IBackupAgent.java:71)
                                             at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:446)
04-02 14:01:33.981 1626-1636/? E/StrictMode: A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
                                         java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'close' not called
                                             at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:184)
                                             at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.<init>(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:180)
                                             at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor$1.createFromParcel(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:916)
                                             at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor$1.createFromParcel(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:906)
                                             at android.app.IBackupAgent$Stub.onTransact(IBackupAgent.java:57)
                                             at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:446)
04-02 14:01:33.984 1626-1636/? E/StrictMode: A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
                                         java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'close' not called
                                             at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:184)
                                             at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.<init>(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:180)
                                             at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor$1.createFromParcel(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:916)
                                             at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor$1.createFromParcel(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:906)
                                             at android.app.IBackupAgent$Stub.onTransact(IBackupAgent.java:64)
                                             at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:446)
04-02 14:01:34.001 1626-1636/? E/StrictMode: A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
                                         java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'close' not called
                                             at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:184)
                                             at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.<init>(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:180)
                                             at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor$1.createFromParcel(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:916)
                                             at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor$1.createFromParcel(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:906)
                                             at android.app.IBackupAgent$Stub.onTransact(IBackupAgent.java:71)
                                             at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:446)
```

Here are all of the errors

Here's my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/logo"
    android:label="workout"
    android:theme="@style/MyTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Main2Activity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main2">
        <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>


        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
</application>
<receiver android:name=".Alarm_Receiver1"/>
<receiver android:name=".Alarm_Receiver2"/>
```

styles.xml:

```
<resources>

    <style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>">

</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/colorVerd</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorBlanc</item>
</style>
```

Comment: in your manifest add a theme

Comment: I'm pretty confident they're coming from your code.

Comment: "Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity."

Comment: Your MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity. For the you need to use Theme.AppCompat in your Manifest.xml

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25544021/a-resource-was-acquired-at-attached-stack-trace-but-never-released-see-java-io

Comment: Or simply Change the Java inheritance from ActionBarActivity or AppCompactActivity  to Activity and leave the dialog theme in the manifest as it is.

Comment: logcat says: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity, would you post styles.xml file contents?

Comment: Posted the xml, have a look at it. @NaN

Comment: I've posted the xml @Kathi

Comment: I've posted the xml @AdeelShahzad

Comment: I meant STYLES.XML

Comment: Done @NaN sorry, for the mistake

Comment: Just change MyTheme parent to an Appcompat Theme and let us know if it worked.

Comment: Now it works but I dont get the theme i wanted where there was a green action bar with the name of the app and its logo, it appears with a white action bar with the name of the activity, not the name of the app, and with no logo @NaN

Comment: <resources> <style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light"> <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item> </style> <style name="MyActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light"> <item name="android:background">@color/colorVerd</item> <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorBlanc</item> </style> </resources>     @NaN

Comment: @AlexiaWhite check my answer

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Appcompat Themes instead of Holo themes

Replace `Theme.Holo.Light` with `Theme.AppCompat.Light`

(I think that's the corresponding one, there's also one with `NoActionBar`)

Also, this line looks misconfigured in your XML. There's an extra quote at the end.

```
<item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>">
```

Comment: Now it works but I dont get the theme i wanted where there was a green  action bar with the name of the app and its logo, it appears with a white action bar with the name of the activity, not the name of the app, and with no logo @cricket_007

Comment: <resources>

    <style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>

    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="android:background">@color/colorVerd</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorBlanc</item>
    </style>

</resources>    @cricket_007

Comment: And what happens when you use the `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`? I don't know what your code is doing, so you very likely could be loading in two Toolbars. I recommend finding a tutorial on how to properly implement the AppCompatActivity with a toolbar because you are missing some colors from the theme style

Answer (score -1):

add this in your manifest file

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Comment: it didn't, already had that on my app but thanks @Nitesh Kumar